# Importing HTML Report into Excel Using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

When you right-click an html document (.html) and open as "Excel", Excel will open up and retain the html appearance in the sheet.

I am trying to write VBA code to import an HTML file (.html) into the worksheet while retaining the HTML look. (I do not want the html code to appear in the sheet).

How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Workbooks.Open("yourfile.HTML") ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wb as excel.workbook
set wb = workbooks.open("C:\test_file.html")
```